# Aspx Send Mail Error

Tags: asp.net, email, web-config, send

Is there any problem in Web.config? When i sent mail i get this error.I think error is in the Web.config file.As you can see i dont know ASPX.I just want to edit codes and send mail to another adress

Thanks for your help

[image: Error Image]

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
      -->
    <configuration>
        <appSettings>
            <!--# Eposta gönderme ayarları-->
            <add key="epostaFromAddress" value="noreply@hkl.com"/>
            <add key="epostaReply" value="noreply@hkl.com"/>
            <add key="epostaFromName" value="hkl Info"/>
            <add key="epostaServer" value="mail.hkl.com"/>
            <add key="epostaSSL" value="0"/>
            <add key="epostaPort" value="26"/>
            <add key="epostaUser" value="noreply@hkl.com"/>
            <add key="epostaPass" value="Gesa123456"/>
            <add key="epostaTo" value="info@hkl.com"/>
        </appSettings>
        <connectionStrings/>
        <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
                <assemblies>
                    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
          </assemblies></compilation>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: _Maybe_. The error says it's trying to connect but can't because the -_"target machine is actively refusing"_. Could be from invalid setting/info in the config (mailserver, username/pwd, etc), but not necessarily the config itself. There's typically some `mailSettings` in config, but isn't "necessary" (can be config in code - which is what it _looks like_ based on your post).

Comment: You also have to check your Firewall settings.